# sshd binding to wrong IPv6 address

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ipv6

I have setup sshd to bind to a specific IPv6 address with this line in my `sshd_config`

```
ListenAddress fd00::ba88:e3ff:fefb:7bf0
```

After testing, I noticed that I was no longer able to connect over IPv6 at all. Checking `netstat` showed that for some reason the last 16 bits of the address were ignored and it bound to a non-existent address.

```
$ sudo netstat -npl | grep sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4944/sshd
tcp6       0      0 fd00::ba88:e3ff:fefb:22 :::*                    LISTEN      4944/sshd
```

Checking `ifconfig` yields these IPv6 addresses

```
$ ifconfig | grep inet6
      inet6 addr: fd00::ba88:e3ff:fefb:7bf0/64 Scope:Global
      inet6 addr: fe80::ba88:e3ff:fefb:7bf0/64 Scope:Link
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
```

Where did I go wrong in configuring the daemon?

Comment: Passing the -T argument to netstat will print the full untruncated IPv6 address. Try that and see what you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default `netstat` will truncate the IP addresses it shows such that address and port number will fit in 23 characters. If you want the full addresses to be shown, you need to provide the `-W` or `--wide` flag to `netstat`

If you use this command, it should show you that `sshd` is listening on the address you asked for:

```
sudo netstat -nplW | grep sshd
```

What you should fix however is the address you have assigned, since it is violating RFC 4193 and that is likely going to cause you problems at some point. RFC 4193 is designed to prevent address collisions, but when you don't follow the standard it won't prevent collisions. An address assigned according to the specification could look like this: `fde8:ca75:a94b::ba88:e3ff:fefb:7bf0`

Comment: Thanks for that hint, but I did not set that address myself. Complain to AVM for having their routers assign standard-violating addresses.